# Exiting a do while loop with string comparison

Tags: java

Newbie help needed. The purpose is to load an array from user input. When the user types "EXIT" they should exit the loop, but my string comparison is not working. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
    //Declare Variables
    String[] a = new String[50];
    String CompareValue = "";
    String CondChecker = "EXIT";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Prompt user for input
    System.out.println("What is the name? "); 

    //Load array
    do {
            for(int j=0; j<50; j++){    
                a[j]= sc.next();
                CompareValue = a[j];
                System.out.println("Another name? ");
                CompareValue = a[j];
            }   
    //Check exit condition
    } while(!CompareValue.equals(CondChecker));
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Java but is it case sensitive?  Would you need to force `CompareValue` to upper case?

Comment: Why do you need an inner loop for ?, Edit: I would recommend you to debug the program, which greatly helped me when I was studying programming.

Comment: Explain more clearly what your program is supposed to do. Maybe read names into an array until an empty name or 50 have been read, whichever comes first? Maybe read a name then 50 elements, until an empty name is entered?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `for` loop

```
int j = -1;
do {
                j++;
                a[j]= sc.next();
                CompareValue = a[j];
                System.out.println("Another name? ");
                CompareValue = a[j];
    //Check exit condition
    } while(!CompareValue.equals(CondChecker));
```

Comment: Now `j` is not defined.

Comment: @clcto before `do{` add `int j = 0;` and then after `CompareValue = a[j]` increment j using `j++;`

Comment: @zgc7009 that should probably be added to the answer is all I am saying.

Comment: @clcto thought it was your question, was trying to help :P

Answer (score 0):

Your while check is breaking the do loop. But you are still not breaking the 50 iterations of for loop, if the input is EXIT.